# Comparing two vectors

Tags: python, numpy

I have some code where I want to test if the product of a matrix and vector is the zero vector. An example of my attempt is:

```
n =2
zerovector = np.asarray([0]*n)

for column in itertools.product([0,1], repeat = n):
    for row in itertools.product([0,1], repeat = n-1):
        M = toeplitz(column, [column[0]]+list(row))
        for v in itertools.product([-1,0,1], repeat = n):
            vector = np.asarray(v)
            if (np.dot(M,v) == zerovector):
                print M, "No good!"
                break
```

But the line `if (np.dot(M,v) == zerovector):` gives the error `ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()`. What is the right way to do this?

Comment: Your inner loop will always `break` since you include the zero vector in your test vectors, which will certainly be in the kernel of `M`.  What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: @SvenMarnach The code isn't finished but thank you you are right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that `==` between two arrays is an element-wise comparison—you get back an array of boolean values. An array of boolean values isn't a boolean value itself, so you can't use it in an `if`. This is what the error is trying to tell you.

You *could* solve this by using the [`all`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.all.html#numpy.ndarray.all) method, to check whether all of the elements in the boolean array are true. But you're making this way more complicated than you need to. Nonzero values are truthy, zero values are falsey, so you can just use [`any`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.any.html#numpy.ndarray.any) without a comparison:

```
if not np.dot(M, v).any():
```

If you want to make the comparison to zero explicit, just compare to a scalar, don't build a zero vector; it'll get broadcast the same way. And, if you ever *do* want to build a zero vector, just use the [`zeros`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.zeros.html) function; don't build a `list` of zeros in a complicated way and pass it to `asarray`.

You could also use the [`count_nonzero`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.count_nonzero.html#numpy.count_nonzero) function here as a different alternative. If it returns anything truthy (that is, any non-zero number), the array had at least one non-zero.

In general, you're making almost everything harder than necessary, and working through a brief NumPy tutorial and then scanning the main docs pages for useful functions would really help you.

---

Also, if your values aren't integers, you probably don't actually want to compare `== 0` in the first place. Floating-point numbers accumulate rounding errors. To handle that, use the [`allclose`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) function instead.

Comment: Thanks that worked.  Any tips for how to improve the rest of the code gratefully received.  All the values are integers in my case.

Answer (score 1):

as the error says you need to use `all`

```
if all(np.dot(M,v) == zerovector):
```

or `np.all`. `np.dot(M,v) == zerovector` gives you a vector which is pair-wise comparison of the two vectors.

Comment: Using the builtin `all` will work, but it forces you to iterate the vector in Python instead of letting NumPy do it more quickly. In general, you want to keep the iteration inside NumPy whenever possible.